# Why is this the output of sub() in R?

Tags: r, regex, substitution

I have the following vector and code (bolded) given to me by an exercise for DataCamp's R course.

```
awards <- c("Won 1 Oscar.",
  "Won 1 Oscar. Another 9 wins & 24 nominations.",
  "1 win and 2 nominations.",
  "2 wins & 3 nominations.",
  "Nominated for 2 Golden Globes. 1 more win & 2 nominations.",
  "4 wins & 1 nomination.")

sub( ".*\ \s([0-9]+)\ \snomination.*$", "\ \1", awards)

# Output: 
[1] "Won 1 Oscar." "24"           "2"            "3"            "2"           
[6] "1"
```

I understand that the code has substituted the number of nominations for the entire phrase. I don't understand the following:

- How `\\1` corresponds to each number (it seems like it should just be replaced by the number 1?)
- Why the first part of the phrase (e.g. "4 wins &...") is also
  replaced, when it seems like it should just be everything after the space before nominations.

Comment: I think for it to work, it should be `sub(".*\\s([0-9]+)\\snomination.*$", " \\1", awards)` But `\\1` is a backreference to the digits in capture group 1. If there is a match, it will be replaced with capture group 1. If there is no match, then there is nothing to replace, and the first line will be unchanged. The `.* ` part at the beginning of the pattern also matches `4 wins` as the dot matches any character and the pattern is greedy and nothing in the pattern instructs to stop at `4 wins`

Answer (score 1):

> How \1 corresponds to each number (it seems like it should just be replaced by the number 1?)

In regex replacement, `\1` refers to the first "capturing group" that is matched be your first set of parentheses. (If you had multiple sets of parentheses, you could refer to the second with `\2`, etc.)

> Why the first part of the phrase (e.g. "4 wins &...") is also replaced, when it seems like it should just be everything after the space before nominations.

`sub` replaces the entire match. Not just the capturing groups. You can read about *look-ahead* and *look-behind* regex if you want to condition look beyond the pattern.

A couple other notes:

- Your code seems to be escaping spaces with `"\ "`, which shouldn't be necessary.
- There are excellent regex visualization/education tools like regex101.com - I'd strongly recommend using those to better understand and debug regex.